# Why are not all hosts listed in the TestComplete 8 Network Suite Wizard?

Tags: testcomplete8

I want to use the Network Suite Wizard. So I go to "Test" - "Create Distributed Test...". Then I press "Add Hosts...". My problem is that not all hosts are listed here. What can I do about this? I can ping the desired host that is not in the list.

Comment: Which network suite wizard are you referring to?  If this is part of a tool, please state its name.

Comment: I tagged my question with the product, I am talking about TestComplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why:**

Windows API methods are used to get the computers list. There may be network policy restrictions or issues that prevent some nodes to appear on the list Windows returns. What I would check is whether the unavailable nodes appear under the Network node in Windows Explorer. If they are there, but not visible in TC's dialogs, this would be strange.

**What to do:**

Go to the Hosts editor, add a new Host. After that, you can specify the needed computer's IP address or a network name in the inline editor of the Address field (without opening the PC selection dialog).

I hopes this helps!

Comment: Exactly, they are not listed in the Windows Explorer neither. I already took the manual path. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Cool! Would you mind marking the response as accepted? ;)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on two things: first, TestComplete8 or TestExecute8 must be installed on each system you're planning to use as a host (as described on the SmartBear [help site](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/27241/) - this requirement has not changed between TestComplete8 and TestComplete9)

Second, your network configuration and firewall setup must permit TestComplete to communicate through its own dedicated ports.

Comment: Kate, it is actually not needed to have TC or TE on some host to make the host appear in the dialog. The dialog lists the avialable network PCs using Windows API methods, it does not "talk" to the TC/TE service on the remote computers.

Comment: All workstations and notebooks are listed there, the servers are missing. I can add them manually however in the  Hosts section. Verify works and deploying projects to those servers also works.

Comment: My misunderstanding - I was reading "host" as "machine that will be running a network project" rather than "server" - apologies for the confusion.